# Embed variables in very simple javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi for some reason I can't get this function to work.

```
function go(type)
{
    location=document.category.example.options[document.category.example.selectedIndex].value
}
```

All i want to do is embed the type variable, the go function becomes undefined whenever I try to do something like

```
location=document.'+type+'.example.options[document.'+type+'.example.selectedIndex].value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `document.'+type+'.example.options[document.'+type+'.example.selectedIndex].value` you should write:

```
document[type].example.options[document[type].example.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document[type].example`

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn more about JavaScript syntax before you do stuff like that.

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
function go(type)
{
    location=document[type].example.options[document[type].example.selectedIndex].value;
}

go('category');
```

It takes advantage of the fact that these two are equivalent:

```
a.b === a['b']
```

But obviously in the second part, b can be replaced dynamically since it is a string.